# React Module: accept parameters and export multi values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a source code like this:

```
// createStore.js
export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const store = ...;
  return store;
}
```

Another file will called by:

```
import createStore from './store/createStore';
const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
const store = createStore(initialState);
```

My question is: I want createStore function can return true value, for example `store` and `customHistory`, How can I do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an object.

```
return {
  store: {...},
  customHistory: {...}
}
```

Comment: By using  import.

Comment: Yep. I'm using this: `const {store, customHistory} = createStore(initialState);`
but looks like it doesn't work.

Comment: That looks correct to me, so long as your createStore is using a return like the one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
// createStore.js
export default {
    create: (storeparam1, storeparam2, ...) => {
        // do something with your store
        store={}

    return store;
  }
}
```

then in the file where you want to use it, include it by:

```
// check if the file is in your current folder or not
import createStore from './createStore';

var store = createStore.create(param1, param2);
```